# Add/remove box in html using angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to create/use an add-remove box like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4FaW.jpg) in HTML using angularJS where you have a list of some objects on the left and you select the objects to put them on under the headings listed on the right. Any idea what do we call such tables/lists and can I create/find them?

Comment: check out http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-sortable/, it should help you, and channel your search to sortable list with angular instead quite some libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is the accurate title to call it :)

but I tried to implement a sample of 'add/remove box' to achieve the concept you want with **AngularJS**!

the main part consists of three sections:

1. **left section** which is going to be **added**
2. **middle section** which contains the **buttons**
3. **right section** which is going to be **removed**

The code below applies the above section which aforesaid:

```
<div class="box leftBox">
    <div>
        <div id="{{left.name}}" ng-click="clicked($event, 0)" data-ng-repeat="left in lefts">{{left.name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box button_holder">
    <button ng-click="add()" class="button button-blue">ADD ></button>
    <button ng-click="remove()" class="button button-red">< REMOVE</button>
    <button ng-click="addAll()" class="button button-blue button-dark">ADD ALL >></button>
    <button ng-click="removeAll()" class="button button-red button-dark"><< REMOVE ALL</button>
    <button ng-click="deleteChoice()" class="button delete">X</button>
</div>

<div class="box rightBox">
    <div>
        <div ng-click="clicked($event, 1)" data-ng-repeat="right in rights">{{right.name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

by using angularjs directives including `data-ng-repeat` you can control the procedure of adding or removing

> **[here](https://alirezakay.github.io/projects/phase1/AddRemoveBox-AngularJS/) is the implemented overview**.
>
> **[here](https://codepen.io/alireza79797979/pen/PKxMgv) is the completed code on the "codepen"**.

**you can also check [my github](https://github.com/alirezakay/AddRemoveBox-AngularJS)**.

try to run the **snippet** in a **fullscreen window**!

```js
/**
 * Created by ALIREZA on 8/30/2017.
 */

var app = angular.module('Add_Remove_Box', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  var i;
  var isRepeated = false;
  var actionLicense = true;
  var prevElement = null;
  var currentElement = null;
  var positionSide = null;

  $scope.choices = ["left", "right"];

  $scope.lefts = [{
    id: 'left1'
  }, {
    id: 'left2'
  }, {
    id: 'left3'
  }, {
    id: 'left4'
  }];
  for (i = 0; i < $scope.lefts.length; i++) {
    $scope.lefts[i].name = "left" + (i + 1).toString();
  }

  $scope.rights = [{
    id: 'right1'
  }, {
    id: 'right2'
  }];
  for (i = 0; i < $scope.rights.length; i++) {
    $scope.rights[i].name = "right" + (i + 1).toString();
  }

  $scope.insert = function($event) {
    var side = $scope.selectedSide;
    if (side == null || side == "left") {
      var leftItemNo = $scope.lefts.length + 1;
      $scope.lefts.push({
        'id': 'left' + leftItemNo
      });
      $scope.lefts[leftItemNo - 1].name = $scope.choice.name;
    } else {
      var rightItemNo = $scope.rights.length + 1;
      $scope.rights.push({
        'id': 'right' + rightItemNo
      });
      $scope.rights[rightItemNo - 1].name = $scope.choice.name;
    }
  };

  $scope.deleteChoice = function() {
    if (positionSide === 0) {
      var ItemNo = -1;
      $scope.lefts.forEach(function(i, j) {
        if (i.name === currentElement.textContent) {
          ItemNo = j;
          return;
        }
      });
      $scope.lefts.splice(ItemNo, 1);
    }
  };

  $scope.add = function() {
    if (actionLicense && positionSide === 0) {
      actionLicense = false;

      var leftItemNo = -1;
      $scope.lefts.forEach(function(i, j) {
        if (i.name === currentElement.textContent) {
          leftItemNo = j;
          return;
        }
      });
      $scope.lefts.splice(leftItemNo, 1);

      var rightItemNo = $scope.rights.length + 1;
      $scope.rights.push({
        'id': 'right' + rightItemNo
      });
      $scope.rights[rightItemNo - 1].name = currentElement.textContent;

    }
  };

  $scope.remove = function() {
    if (actionLicense && positionSide === 1) {
      actionLicense = false;

      var rightItemNo = -1;
      $scope.rights.forEach(function(i, j) {
        if (i.name === currentElement.textContent) {
          rightItemNo = j;
          return;
        }
      });
      $scope.rights.splice(rightItemNo, 1);

      var leftItemNo = $scope.lefts.length + 1;
      $scope.lefts.push({
        'id': 'left' + leftItemNo
      });
      $scope.lefts[leftItemNo - 1].name = currentElement.textContent;

    }
  };

  $scope.addAll = function() {

    $scope.lefts.forEach(function(i) {
      var rightItemNo = $scope.rights.length + 1;
      $scope.rights.push({
        'id': 'right' + rightItemNo
      });
      $scope.rights[rightItemNo - 1].name = i.name;

    });
    $scope.lefts.splice(0, $scope.lefts.length);

  };

  $scope.removeAll = function() {

    $scope.rights.forEach(function(i) {
      var leftItemNo = $scope.lefts.length + 1;
      $scope.lefts.push({
        'id': 'left' + leftItemNo
      });
      $scope.lefts[leftItemNo - 1].name = i.name;

    });
    $scope.rights.splice(0, $scope.rights.length);

  };


  $scope.clicked = function($event, pos) {

    actionLicense = true;
    positionSide = pos;
    currentElement = $event.currentTarget;

    var deleteButton = document.getElementsByClassName("delete")[0];
    if (pos === 1) {
      if (deleteButton.className.indexOf("button-deactive") === -1) {
        deleteButton.className += " button-deactive";
      }
    } else {
      deleteButton.className = deleteButton.className.replace(" button-deactive", "");
    }

    if (prevElement === null) {
      prevElement = currentElement;
    } else {
      if (prevElement === currentElement) {
        isRepeated = !isRepeated;
      } else {
        if (isRepeated) {
          isRepeated = false;
        }
      }
    }
    if (prevElement.className.indexOf("active") !== -1) {
      prevElement.className = prevElement.className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    if (!isRepeated && currentElement.className.indexOf("active") === -1) {
      currentElement.className += " active";
    }
    prevElement = currentElement;
  };

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  border: #E64A19 inset .7vh;
  background: #616161;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #9bc5c3, #616161);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #9bc5c3, #616161);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

.addItems {
  height: 10vh;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 80vh;
  border: #cfcfcf outset 2px;
  color: #eee;
  font-size: medium;
}

.box>div {
  border: #FFF59D ridge 2px;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.box>div>div {
  padding: 7px;
  border-bottom: #FFF59D ridge 2px;
}

.box>div>div:hover {
  background-color: rgba(100, 150, 220, .5);
  transition: background-color .4s ease;
}

.box>button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 5% 15%;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px 24px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 10px rgba(22, 22, 22, .1);
}

.button:hover {
  transition: all 60ms ease;
  opacity: .95;
  box-shadow: #444 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.button-blue {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #416dea;
}

.button-red {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #F32C52;
}

.button-dark {
  filter: brightness(85%) contrast(110%);
}

.leftBox {
  width: 40%;
}

.button_holder {
  width: 20%;
}

.rightBox {
  width: 40%;
}

input[type="text"],
select {
  padding: 5px;
}

.active {
  transition: all .1s ease;
  background-color: #888;
  color: #000;
  ;
  border: dotted 1px black;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(97, 97, 97, .5);
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.button-deactive {
  opacity: .5;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.button-deactive:hover {
  opacity: .5;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>AddRemoveBox</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <!--include angularJs-->

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container" ng-app="Add_Remove_Box" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <fieldset class="addItems">
      <legend>Insert Items</legend>
      <select ng-model="selectedSide">
            <option ng-repeat="choice in choices">{{choice}}</option>
        </select>
      <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="" placeholder="Enter The Item Name">
      <button class="button insert" value="insert" ng-click="insert($event)">Insert</button>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="box leftBox">
      <div>
        <div id="{{left.name}}" ng-click="clicked($event, 0)" data-ng-repeat="left in lefts">{{left.name}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box button_holder">
      <button ng-click="add()" class="button button-blue">ADD ></button>
      <button ng-click="remove()" class="button button-red">< REMOVE</button>
      <button ng-click="addAll()" class="button button-blue button-dark">ADD ALL >></button>
      <button ng-click="removeAll()" class="button button-red button-dark"><< REMOVE ALL</button>
      <button ng-click="deleteChoice()" class="button delete">X</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box rightBox">
      <div>
        <div ng-click="clicked($event, 1)" data-ng-repeat="right in rights">{{right.name}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, since I was also not able to find the name or any precooked recipe for the given box so I also designed and coded it in the similar way. :-)